# "Better either of the other ways" (meaning)

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the movie the avenger:endgame, valyrie said to hulk as the "talking hulk" -a combination of bruce and the green hulk in one- seeing him again.

Valkyrie said:

> "I think I like you better either of the other ways"

What does this phrase means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the outward appearance of the Hulk has been changing. Valkyrie has now seen him in three different guises. She thinks that this third 'way he looks' is the least appealing.

The word "way" as used here refers to a way or manner of arranging one's outward appearance. In real life it is used to talk about clothing, hairstyles, and the application of cosmetics. Examples:

> I like the way you have done your hair.
>
> I think my hair looked better the other way.
>
> I do not like the way the jacket sits on my shoulders.